# Dependence of $S$-matrix on a coordinate system in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, coordinate-systems, scattering, s-matrix-theory

The $S$-matrix is defined as follows (see e.g. Section 3.2 in Weinberg's "The quantum theory of fields"):
$$S=\lim\exp(iH_0\tau)\exp(-iH(\tau-\tau_0))\exp(-iH_0\tau_0),$$
where the limit is taken when $\tau\to +\infty,\, \tau_0\to -\infty$, $H$ is the full Hamiltonian,and $H_0$ is the free Hamiltonian.

It appears that the definition of the $S$-matrix depends on the choice of the time axis.

> **Does the $S$-matrix really depend on the choice of time axis?**

In other words, if one chooses another coordinate system, does one get a different $S$-matrix $S'$? I would expect to get a conjugate matrix $S'=U^{-1}SU$. But is it true that $S'=S$?

Comment: The S-matrix has to be Lorentz invariant

Comment: @DavideMorgante: So does it imply positive answer to my question, i.e. $S'=S$?

Comment: @DavideMorgante: Another thing, why $S$-matrix is Lorentz invariant. It is not clear at all from its definition.

Comment: @MKO Poincare invariance of the S-matrix is discussed in Section 3.3

Comment: @JF132: Thanks very much. But this section still does not contain explicit answer to my question in the title (unless I missed it). Does follow from there that the $S$-matrix is independent of the coordinate system?

Comment: @MKO - $S$-matrix is a function of momenta, it has no dependence on coordinates at all. What do you even mean by "independent of coordinate system"

Comment: @Prahar : I mean that if one chooses different coordinate system and constructs $S$-matrix using it, one might get a different function of momenta.